# Lexicographically monotone functions

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions

Let $I$ be a finite set. For a sequence $X = x_1...x_n$ drawn from $I$, define its type, $[X]$, to be $t_1 ... t_k$ if $X$ has $t_1$ terms = $y_1$, $t_2$ terms = $y_2$, etc., where the $y$'s are distinct. (Each type is then a partition of $n$.) Assume the $t$'s are put in nondecreasing order, and order the set of all types lexicographically.  Suppose a real valued function $f$ on $I^n$ is monotone in type, i.e., if $[X] \leq [Y]$, then $f(X) \leq f(Y)$. I want to prove that if we fix any subset of the variables of $f$ and sum over all possible choices of the others, the resulting function of the selected variables must also be monotone in type. The goal is use $f$ to create a joint probability distribution under which sequences with "more repetitions" are more probable.

Note that it is not true that $[XY] \le [ZY]$ if and only if $[X] \le [Z]$, since it is the types that are compared, not the strings themselves. Because of this, it is generally not possible to compare individual terms in the sum over variables not selected, and it seems that a successful attack must somehow group terms appropriately and compare groups rather than individual terms.

One could consider cruder orders than lexicographic, e.g., assume monotonicity in the frequency of the modal character, or even monotonicity in the number of distinct characters: these are easier to think about than lexicographic order, but seem to run into the same difficulties.

Comment: What have you tried to prove this?

Comment: I added some ideas and removed a misleading hypothesis.